# How can generate an NSMutableDictionary with multiple keys and values

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I want to generate a nsmutmutable dictionary with the following structure:

```
"user1": {
            "phone Number": "123-123-1234"
            "email": "me@me.com"
            "title": "sales"
            }
"user1": {
            "phone Number": "123-123-1234"
            "email": "me3@me.com"
            "title": "support"
            }
"user2": {
            "phone Number": "123-123-1234"
            "email": "me3@me.com"
            "title": "management"
            }
```

any of you knows how can I do this?

Comment: Mutable outer dictionary, or a mutable dictionary that contains mutable dictionaries?

Comment: You can't.  The entries must have distinct keys, and you have two entries named "user1".  (And note that the "values" of your "userN" entries are other dictionary objects, not simply structure inside the one dictionary.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - I suspect the two matching keys is a typo and in fact the question is really about how to populate a NSMutableDictionary with key/values - without calling setObject:forKey: repetitively.

Comment: @TomSwift - The OP should learn how to construct it using setObject, et al, before learning the "shorthand" approaches.  Otherwise the comprehension will just not be there.

Comment: @Hot Licks - feel free to post your own answer ;)

Comment: Why not just use NSJSONSerialization to turn it into a dictionary and get a mutable copy of it?

Comment: @Abizern - Yeah, I've done that, to instantiate a static table.  Using the new `@` literal notation is probably better, though, if you're going to hard-code the data in your code.  But JSON is the way to go if you'll be reading it from a file.

Comment: I only mentioned JSON, because that's what the structure looks like. I've seen enough questions on SO to know that questioners do not always put all the relevant information in the question. From the structure it seems like it's a JSON response, and they questioner may not be aware that they can turn it into a Dictionary (or an Array) directly without having to unwrap it first.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* md = [@{   @"user1" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"sales" },

                                    @"user2" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me2@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"support" },

                                    @"user3" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me3@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"management" }

                                                   } mutableCopy];
```

or:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* md2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                @{  @"user1" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"sales" },

                                    @"user2" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me2@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"support" },

                                    @"user3" : @{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me3@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"management" }
                                } ];
```

If you want each inner dictionary to be mutable you can apply the same pattern:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* md3 = [@{  @"user1" : [@{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"sales" } mutableCopy],

                                    @"user2" : [@{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me2@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"support" } mutableCopy],

                                    @"user3" : [@{   @"phone Number" : @"123-123-1234",
                                                    @"email" : @"me3@me.com",
                                                    @"title" : @"management" } mutableCopy]

                               } mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define a 'MyContact' object. Since you want a 'structure', seems like that would do what you want unless I'm missing something:

```
@interface MyContact : NSObject {

@property (retain) PhoneNumber;
@property (retain) Email;

- (id) initWithPhone: phone_ Email: _email;
}
```

...then

```
NSMutableDictionary *people = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
   [MyContact initWithPhone: some_number Email: some_email] , @"user1", 
   [MyContact initWithPhone: other_number Email: other_email], @"user2", nil ] ;
```